# Beginner python - stuck in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop

I have two begininer programs, both using the 'while' function, one works correctly, and the other gets me stuck in a loop. The first program is this;

```
num=54
bob = True
print('The guess a number Game!')


while bob == True:
    guess = int(input('What is your guess?  '))

    if guess==num:
        print('wow! You\'re awesome!')
        print('but don\'t worry, you still suck')
        bob = False
    elif guess>num:
        print('try a lower number')
    else:
        print('close, but too low')

print('game over')``
```

and it gives the predictable output of;

```
The guess a number Game!
What is your guess?  12
close, but too low
What is your guess?  56
try a lower number
What is your guess?  54
wow! You're awesome!
but don't worry, you still suck
game over
```

However, I also have this program, which doesn't work;

```
#define vars
a = int(input('Please insert a number: '))
b = int(input('Please insert a second number: '))

#try a function
def func_tim(a,b):
    bob = True
    while bob == True:
        if a == b:
            print('nice and equal')
            bob = False
        elif b > a:
             print('b is picking on a!')
        else:
            print('a is picking on b!')
#call a function
func_tim(a,b)
```

Which outputs;

```
Please insert a number: 12
Please insert a second number: 14
b is picking on a!
b is picking on a!
b is picking on a!
...(repeat in a loop)....
```

Can someone please let me know why these programs are different? Thank you!

Comment: "while function"?  Do you mean "while statement"?

Comment: `== True` is never the right way to go. Instead of `if a == True:`, always prefer `if a:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second program you never give the user a chance to pick two new numbers if they're not equal.  Put the lines where you get input from the user inside the loop, like this:

```
#try a function
def func_tim():
    bob = True
    while bob == True:
        #define vars
        a = int(input('Please insert a number: '))
        b = int(input('Please insert a second number: '))

        if a == b:
            print('nice and equal')
            bob = False
        elif b > a:
             print('b is picking on a!')
        else:
            print('a is picking on b!')
#call a function
func_tim()
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! Didn't think about where the variables were defined.

Answer (score 4):

In the second example, the user doesn't get a chance to enter a new guess inside the loop, so `a` and `b` remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

in your 2nd program, if `b > a`, you will go back to the loop because `bob` is still `true`. You forgot to ask the user to input again.. try it this way

```
  def func_tim():
    while 1:
       a = int(input('Please insert a number: '))
       b = int(input('Please insert a second number: '))
       if a == b:
           print('nice and equal')
           break
       elif b > a:
           print('b is picking on a!')
       else:
           print('a is picking on b!')


func_tim()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second program doesn't allow the user to reenter his guess if it's not correct. Put the `input` into the while loop.

Additional hint: Don't make checks like `variable == True`, just say `while variable:`.